# Formvalidation duplicate validation when add file.js?v=1.0

Tags: javascript, formvalidation.io

i just add this value in my js files to avoid caching.
But when do a submit in form the validation show double error.

Then, i remove ?v=1.0 from my files and works fine

Before i add ?v=1.0 to my files all functions works fine
But in the right moment i add ?v=1.0 or whatever ?hi=bye ?time=12345678
and i do a click in some form with formvalidation display double error

```
<script type="module" src="/assets/js/main.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>
<script type="module" src="/app.js?v=<?=time()?>"></script>
```

Ref image https://prnt.sc/nmQbamAGfjy3

And if a remove ?v=

```
<script type="module" src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>
```

Works fine
Ref image https://prnt.sc/A34Av7vPvImi

Why happend this?
Its the first time i to this to prevent caching files in browser
It this the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend reading [ask] and [mcve] to learn the best way to ask questions. As is, what you have provided doesn't provide enough information to solve the problem. I do something similar with my Js files and I don't have the problem that you are experiencing.